# When I open Jupyter Notebook there is a Kernel Error appears

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, kernel

I've been trying to work on a Python project about object detection with TensorFlow. Everything was okay until I run my Jupyter Notebook in my environment "tensorflow1". When Jupyter Notebook opens there is a red `Kernel Error` appearing at the top righthand side of my window. When I click it gives a message like

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Yasin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tornado\web.py",
>   line 1699, in _execute
>       result = await result   File "C:\Users\Yasin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tornado\gen.py",
>   line 742, in run
>       yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore   File "C:\Users\Yasin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\handlers.py",
>   line 72, in post
>       type=mtype))   File "C:\Users\Yasin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tornado\gen.py",
>   line 735, in run
>       value = future.result()   File "C:\Users\Yasin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tornado\gen.py",
>   line 742, in run
>       yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore   File "C:\Users\Yasin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py",
>   line 88, in create_session
>       kernel_id = yield self.start_kernel_for_session(session_id, path, name, type, kernel_name)   File
>   "C:\Users\Yasin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tornado\gen.py",
>   line 735, in run
>       value = future.result()   File "C:\Users\Yasin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tornado\gen.py",
>   line 742, in run
>       yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore   File "C:\Users\Yasin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py",
>   line 101, in start_kernel_for_session
>       self.kernel_manager.start_kernel(path=kernel_path, kernel_name=kernel_name)   File
>   "C:\Users\Yasin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tornado\gen.py",
>   line 735, in run
>       value = future.result()   File "C:\Users\Yasin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tornado\gen.py",
>   line 209, in wrapper
>       yielded = next(result)   File "C:\Users\Yasin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\notebook\services\kernels\kernelmanager.py",
>   line 168, in start_kernel
>       super(MappingKernelManager, self).start_kernel(**kwargs)   File "C:\Users\Yasin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\jupyter_client\multikernelmanager.py",
>   line 110, in start_kernel
>       km.start_kernel(**kwargs)   File "C:\Users\Yasin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py",
>   line 240, in start_kernel
>       self.write_connection_file()   File "C:\Users\Yasin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\jupyter_client\connect.py",
>   line 476, in write_connection_file
>       kernel_name=self.kernel_name   File "C:\Users\Yasin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\jupyter_client\connect.py",
>   line 141, in write_connection_file
>       with secure_write(fname) as f:   File "D:\Anaconda\envs\tensorflow1\lib\contextlib.py", line 81, in
>   **enter**
>       return next(self.gen)   File "C:\Users\Yasin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\jupyter_core\paths.py",
>   line 424, in secure_write
>       win32_restrict_file_to_user(fname)   File "C:\Users\Yasin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\jupyter_core\paths.py",
>   line 359, in win32_restrict_file_to_user
>       import win32api
>
> ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be
>   found.

I tried to change the Kernel but I had only one Kernel called "Python3". I tried to remove it and created a new Kernel called "Python tensorflow1". I tried to run the codes with that Kernel and it still gives me that red error.

It also says Failed to start the Kernel.

Comment: what is the output of the command "conda env list"?

Comment: # conda environments:
#
base                  *  D:\Anaconda
tensorflow1              D:\Anaconda\envs\tensorflow1


this is the output of "conda env list"

Answer (score 0):

Please activate the environment tensorflow1 and install ipykernel in that environment uing below commands:

```
conda activate tensorflow1
conda install ipykernel
ipython kernel install --name tensorflow1 --user
```

Then try to use access jupyter notebook using the below command:

```
jupyter notebook
```

If the above steps doesn't work please follow the below steps to create a new conda environment and access jupyter notebook from that environment:

```
conda create -n env_tf -c intel python=3.6
```

Once the conda environment is created successfully, you can list the environment using the below command:

```
conda env list
```

It should be listing :

D:\Anaconda\envs\env_tf

Activate the environment using the below command:

```
conda activate env_tf
```

Install ipykernel in the activated environment:

```
conda install ipykernel

ipython kernel install --name env_tf --user
```

Access jupyter notebook using below command:

```
jupyter notebook
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I followed all the steps and now I am having a blank page expcet base(root) environment. When I type "jupyter notebook" in a specific environment, it opens the chrome page but the page is blank and dashboard is not showing. I did try to open the jupyter notebook on my base environment and it runs perfectly fine but it does not run on different virtual environments.

Comment: Which OS are you using?